# Find the P (High School Graduate | Smoker), and P (Smoker | High School Graduate). Are these the same? Why?

Tags: probability, statistics

Education level and smoking: Employees at a large factory were surveyed and classified according to the level of education and whether they smoke or not.

\begin{array}{r|c|c|c}
      & \text{not HS graduate} & \text{HS graduate} & \text{College graduate}\\\hline
\text{smoke} & 6 & 14 & 19\\\hline
\text{do not smoke} & 18 & 7 & 25
\end{array}

If an employee is selected randomly find these probabilities:
a. The employee smokes given that she/he graduated from college
b. Given that the employee did not graduate from High school,she/he is a smoker.
c. Find the P (High School Graduate | Smoker), and P (Smoker | High School Graduate).  Are these the same?  Why or why not?

Comment: no, they are not necessarily the same.  In principle it might be true that every high school gradate smoked but some non-graduates also smoked (for example).

Comment: $P(HSG|S) = \frac{P(HSG \cap S)}{P(S)}$ and $P(S|HSG) = \frac{P(HSG \cap S)}{P(HSG)}$, so the two are equal if and only if $P(HSG) = P(S)$.

Comment: Oh, or if $P(HSG \cap S) = 0$.

Comment: What information did you have to get your probabilities, and how did you work it out?

Comment: For future reference, we also ask for your work, not just a copy of the problem. You can find a detailed formatting tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 4):

Let

$A : \text{High School Graduate}$

$B : \text{ Smoker}$

$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} \,\,\, ;\,\,P(B|A)=\frac{P(B \cap A)}{P(A)}$$

If you want them to same, then
\begin{align}
P(A|B)=P(B|A) &\implies \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(B \cap A)}{P(A)}\\
& \implies \text{either} ~ {P(A)=P(B)}\,\, ~\text{(or)}~~ {P(A \cap B)=0}
\end{align}